# Append individual Pandas DataFrame Rows to List and turn into Matrices

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matrix

I have a csv of hundred of rows each holding unique values that need to stay together. They are in this format:

```
 WordTeams (column name)
 1 cat, dog, frisbee, person, rat
 2 mouse, cheese, saw, mat, moose
```

I am trying to use pandas to turn them into a list to look like this:

```
[cat, dog, frisbee, person, rat]
[mouse, cheese, saw, mat, moose]
```

I am new to pandas and cannot figure out how to append individual rows to lists.

Finally, I hope to turn these lists into matrices that compare against themselves, like below. I intend to populate the values by calling each cell value to an api. How would I use pandas to structure my data into such matrices?

```
   cat dog frisbee person rat
cat
dog
frisbee
person
rat
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `str.split` split string to list

```
df.Name=df.Name.str.split(',')
df
Out[681]: 
0    [cat,  dog,  frisbee,  person,  rat]
1    [mouse,  cheese,  saw,  mat,  moose]
```

Then using `pandas.DataFrame` create your matrix

```
pd.DataFrame(index=df.Name[0],columns=df.Name[0])
Out[683]: 
          cat  dog  frisbee  person  rat
 cat      NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 dog      NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 frisbee  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 person   NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 rat      NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
```

For update value

```
df1.loc['dog','cat']=1
df1
Out[697]: 
          cat  dog  frisbee  person  rat
 cat      NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 dog      NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 frisbee  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 person   NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 rat      NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
 dog        1  NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN
```

Data Input

```
data = {"Name":["cat, dog, frisbee, person, rat","mouse, cheese, saw, mat, moose"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
Out[685]: 
                             Name
0  cat, dog, frisbee, person, rat
1  mouse, cheese, saw, mat, moose
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful! I have a quick followup, how could I go about setting up an iteration create a unique matrix for every row as opposed to simply using one as an example?

Comment: @tesh you need for loop here

Answer (score 0):

First I would start by importing the csv with pandas.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer)
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html for more details on the import

Now you would like to extract rows from the dataframe and create a new dataframe matrix. You could do something similar to this:

```
for item in df.as_matrix():
    df_temp = pandas.DataFrame(index=item, columns=item)
    print(df_temp)
```

This should give a matrix with index and column names corresponding to each row in the csv file you import.